# Creating URL shortcut for web application hosted on Azure Virtual Machine from on-premise

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-virtual-network

I have a webforms application that is hosted on an Azure VM that is deployed within a virtual network on Azure. The virtual network is subsequently connected to our on-premise servers via VPN connection and we are able to access the form application from 10.101.1.5/forms

How can I create a URL redirect/alias so that when users type /webforms they will be redirected to the application at 10.101.1.5/forms. Would this need to be put in place on the server of the on-premise device or on the Azure VM

Comment: Aside from putting an alias in the hosts file?

Comment: I have updated the hosts file on the Azure VM server to contain 10.101.1.5 but if I type the name it wont resolve, I also want to go to the /forms level of the URL redirection, the application is hosted on an Apache web server and I have only real had experience with IIS to date so I am unsure about this

Answer (score 0):

The alias should be on premise. The rest is just redirecting the request to 10.101.1.5 and this should directly work as both machines are on the same subnet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so if it was on 10.101.1.5/forms and I wanted this to be accessible by the Url http://webforms/ how would I update the file

Comment: 10.101.1.5 webforms

should work. on more info on connecting cross premises on Azure VNETS  link below might help.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/#name-resolution-using-your-own-dns-server

Comment: 10.101.1.5 takes me to the IBM web server home page but I want to redirect this to 10.101.1.5/forms which is where the actual application is hosted

Comment: ok, AFAIK this isn't possible using the hosts file. However, you probably can handle this using your web server settings. You should be able to redirect everything coming from the virtual network to a specific subdomain. In this case anything from the subnet to 10.101.1.5/forms. Alternatively you can deploy a DNS server and do the name resolution, which might be overkill in this case.